Efficient Algorithm to Estimate $n$ Largest Eigenvalues of Symmetric Matrix
Suppose we have a large symmetric matrix $A_{m \times m}$ where $m >> n$. We indeed can compute the n largest eigenpairs iteratively on matrices $A_i = A_{i-1} - \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$, where $A_0 = A$ is the original matrix and $\lambda_i$, $v_i$ are the corresponding eigenpairs, to obtain these eigenvalues. I wonder if there exist more efficient algorithm to compute eigenvalues without worrying about eigenvectors, or to extract a matrix of simpler form which contains the information about largest $n$ eigenpairs only.
What is the most efficient algorithm known to solve this?

doesn't standard eigensolver work for your problem? for instance eigs in matlab.

@Yimin I know there are ways to obtains eigenvalues only, such as numpy.linalg.eigvals. However, I would also like to understand how it is implemented.

You can take a look at the source code in numpy for the implementation details. This is implemented using the ``_geev`` LAPACK routines which compute     the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of general square arrays.

and also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808510/which-algorithm-do-dggev-or-dsygv-eigen-solvers-in-lapack-implement-is-it-qz

It seems like the LAPACK routine for calculating eigenvalues for symmetric matrices boils down to two major steps:

Tridiagnolize the symmetric matrix, i.e. iteratively conjugating it by Orthogonal matrices (which can be carry out using Householder matrices).
Find eigenvalues using rational variant of TQR algorithm proposed by Pal, Walker and Kahan. I am quite unfamiliar with this part. Please add some detail if capable.

references:

LAPACK DSYEV
LAPACK DSYTRD
LAPACK DSTERF


$$
{\bf A}\left\vert\Psi_{n}\right\rangle = \left\vert\Phi_{n}\right\rangle,\qquad
\left\vert\Psi_{n + 1}\right\rangle = {\left\vert\Phi_{n}\right\rangle \over \lambda_{n}}
$$
where $\lambda_{n}$ is the largest -in magnitude- of the components of $\left\vert\Phi_{n}\right\rangle$. As you iterates this algorithm, $\lambda_{n}$ goes to the coveted eigenvalue.

Could you please clarify the notation you are using？I am not familiar with the brackets

If the above algorithm describes the power method, I believe it only finds the largest one but not all largest n eigen-values at once. We still have to reduce it to matrices that eliminates the largest one to find all n eigen-values.

@GabriellaChaos You are right. It’s the first step to the whole goal.

@GabriellaChaos $\left\vert a\right\rangle \equiv \left(\begin{array}{c}a_{1} \ a_{2} \ \vdots \ a_{n}\end{array}\right).\qquad$ It’s just a convenient notation.

Then how could you reduce the matrix without knowing the corresponding eigen-vector?
